# On the HSK5 paper-based exam, can I do the writing section before the reading section?

Tags: chinese, exams, hsk

Since I can handwrite characters, I signed up for the paper-based (handwritten) HSK5 exam.  This will be my first time taking this exam, so I'm not familiar with the specifics.

If allowable, I would like to complete the writing section before the reading section.  I'm hoping to first complete the writing section (which I think I can do in around 30 minutes), and save the remaining time for the reading section.

**Question**: On the HSK5 paper-based exam, can I do the writing section before the reading section?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: I took the HSK5 exam yesterday, and I did the writing section before the reading section.  There was someone in the room watching, she didn't say anything.

So I'm not sure if it's officially allowed, but nobody said anything when I did it.